# FileNotFoundError while scraping images

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written this script to download images from a subreddit.

```
# A script to download pictures from reddit.com/r/HistoryPorn
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import sys #TODO: sys.argv

print('Downloading images...')

# Create a directory for photographs
path_to_hist = '/home/tautvydas/Documents/histphoto'
os.chdir(path_to_hist)
if not os.path.exists('/home/tautvydas/Documents/histphoto'):
    os.mkdir(path_to_hist)

website = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/HistoryPorn'

# Go to the internet and connect to the subreddit, start a loop
for i in range(3):
    subreddit = urlopen(website)
    bs_subreddit = BeautifulSoup(subreddit, 'lxml')

    # Create a regex and find all the titles in the page
    remove_reddit_tag = re.compile('(\s*\(i.redd.it\)(\s*))')
    title_bs_subreddit = bs_subreddit.findAll('p', {'class': 'title'})

    # Get text off the page
    pic_name = []
    for item in title_bs_subreddit[1:]:
        item = item.get_text()
        item = remove_reddit_tag.sub('', item)
        pic_name.append(item)

    # Get picture links
    pic_bs_subreddit = bs_subreddit.findAll('div', {'data-url' : re.compile('.*')})
    pic_img = []
    for pic in pic_bs_subreddit[1:]:
        pic_img.append(pic['data-url'])

    # Zip all info into one
    name_link = zip(pic_name, pic_img)
    for i in name_link:
        urlretrieve(i[1],i[0])


    # Click next
    for link in bs_subreddit.find('span', {'class' : 'next-button'}).children:
        website = link['href']
```

However I get this FileNotFoundError.

```
Downloading images...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gethist.py", line 44, in <module>
    urlretrieve(i[1],i[0])
  File "/home/tautvydas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 258, in urlretrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Preparation of rocket carrying test instruments, Kauai. June 29, 1962 [2880x1620] https://www.topic.com/a-crimson-fracture-in-the-sky'
```

What could be the problem? The link in 'data-url' is retrieved fine and works if clicked. Could this be a problem that a name contains a hyperlink? Or the name too long? Because up till that image all other images are downloaded without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to the names collected : they contain the source of the picture as an url string, and it is misinterpreted like a folder path.

You would need to clean the text to avoid special annoying characters and maybe make them a bit shorter, but i suggest to change the pattern too, to ensure the results, you could parse only the `<a>` tags that contain the title, not the whole `<p>` which hold the link too.

Also, instead of building a zip with two different loops, you can create one list of the main blocks by searching the class `thing` (equivalent to `findAll('div', {'data-url' : re.compile('.*')`), and then use this list to perform relative queries on each block to find the title and the url.

```
[...]
remove_reddit_tag = re.compile('(\s*\(i.redd.it\)(\s*))')

name_link = []
for block in bs_subreddit.findAll('div', {'class': 'thing'})[1:]:
    item = block.find('a',{'class': 'title'}).get_text()
    title = remove_reddit_tag.sub('', item)[:100]

    url = block.get('data-url')
    name_link.append((title, url))
    print(url, title)

for title, url in name_link:
    urlretrieve(url, title)
```